# Unable to work with navlist and iframe in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the navlist with a search box my code is given below.

In the UI I want to click each of the items then the page will be replaced by the navlist selected item If the select Company then the company page will show up in iframe and if i select indication the indication page will show up. But for the search term in the query box only output$frame html iframe to show . I might be missing some piecies to acheive this . Any help will be apprecicated ?

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
types = c("Company","Medical Devices","Gene/Protein","Indication","MicroRNA","Drug","Adverse Event","DRUGTYP","Technology","Protein Type")
state.name = c("BRCA1","FITM2","ERS1","BST2","BTK","data","democrat","Republic","love")
shinyUI(navbarPage(
"docsearch",fluidPage(
                      fluidRow(
                          column(8, align="center", offset = 2,
                                 selectizeInput(
                                     'foo', label = "Search For ..",multiple =FALSE, width= '500px', choices = state.name,
                                     options = list(create = TRUE)
                                 )
                          )
                      ),fluidRow(
                          column(6, align="center", offset = 3,
                                 actionButton("searchterm", "Rocket Search"),
                                 tags$style(type='text/css', "#button { vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; width: 60%; font-size: 30px;}")
                          ),br()
                      ), uiOutput('mainframe'),
                          navlistPanel(

                              widths = c(3, 9),id="termlist",
                              tabPanel('Company',value='company',
                                       uiOutput('out')
                              ),
                              tabPanel('Indication',value='indication',
                                       uiOutput('out')
                          ))


)))
```

my server.R is given below

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


################
# search box 
################


observe({ 
  query <- input$foo
  print(query)
  test <<- paste0("http://news.scibite.com/scibites/news.html?  q=GENE$",query)
})
 output$frame <- renderUI({
  input$searchterm
  my_test <- tags$iframe(src=test,frameBorder=0,marginheight=0,height=600, width=1000)
  print(my_test)
  my_test
})

 observe({ 
   if(!is.null(input$termlist)){
  id <- input$termlist
  print (id)
if(id=="company"){
    st <- sprintf("%s&ampspecial=&ampfel=COMPANY&ampsl=",as.character(input$foo))
    test_co <<- paste0("https://news.scibite.com/scibites/facet.html?q=GENE%24",st,sep="")
} else if(id=="indication"){
    st <- sprintf("%s&ampspecial=&ampfel=COMPANY&ampsl=",as.character(input$foo))
    test_co <<- paste0("https://news.scibite.com/scibites/facet.html?q=GENE%24",st,sep="")
   }
  }

 })

output$topic <- renderUI({
#input$Choice
input$termlist
print (input$termlist)
co_test <- tags$iframe(src=test_co,frameBorder=0,marginheight=0,height=600, width=1000)
print(co_test)
co_test
  })

 output$mainframe <- renderUI({

 x <- htmlOutput("frame")
 x

 })
 output$out <- renderUI({

    x <- htmlOutput("topic")
    x
  })
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  i made it work but with lots of code and copy paste .

Here is the ui.R

```
library(shiny)
types = c("Company","Medical        Devices","Gene/Protein","Indication","MicroRNA","Drug","Adverse Event","DRUGTYP","Technology","Protein Type")
state.name =    c("BRCA1","FITM2","ERS1","BST2","BTK","data","democrat","Republic","love")
shinyUI(navbarPage(
"docsearch",fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(8, align="center", offset = 2,
               selectizeInput(
                   'foo', label = "Search For ..",multiple =FALSE, width= '500px', choices = state.name,
                   options = list(create = TRUE)
               )
        )
    ),fluidRow(
        column(6, align="center", offset = 3,
               actionButton("searchterm", "Rocket Search"),
               tags$style(type='text/css', "#button { vertical-align: middle; height: 40px; width: 60%; font-size: 30px;}")
        ),br()
    ),
    navlistPanel(id="terms",well =FALSE,widths = c(2, 6),
                 tabPanel("Main",value="main",
                          htmlOutput("main")
                 ),

                 tabPanel("Drug",value="drug",
                                  htmlOutput("drug")),
                 tabPanel("DrugType/MOA",value="dtmoa",
                                  htmlOutput("dtmoa")))


    )))
```

Here is the server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
            observe({ 
    filterquery <- input$terms
    query <- input$foo
    print(query)
    print(filterquery)
    #if (length(query) == 1){

        if(filterquery == "main"){  
            test_main <<- paste0("http://news.scibite.com/scibites/news.html?q=GENE$",query)
        } else if (filterquery == "company"){
            st <- sprintf("%s&special=&fel=COMPANY&sl=",as.character(input$foo))
            test_com <<- paste0("https://news.scibite.com/scibites/facet.html?q=GENE%24",st,sep="")
        } else if (filterquery == "drug"){
            st <- sprintf("%s&special=&fel=DRUG&sl=",as.character(input$foo))
            test_drug <<- paste0("https://news.scibite.com/scibites/facet.html?q=GENE%24",st,sep="")
        }
     })

  output$main <- renderUI({
    input$searchterm
    m_terms <-       tags$iframe(src=test_main,frameBorder=0,marginheight=0,height=600, width=800)
    print(m_terms)
    m_terms
})
  output$drug <- renderUI({
  input$terms
  d_terms <-    tags$iframe(src=test_drug,frameBorder=0,marginheight=0,height=600, width=800)
   print(d_terms)
    d_terms
  })

  output$dtmoa <- renderUI({
  input$terms
  dtm_terms <- tags$iframe(src=test_dtmoa,frameBorder=0,marginheight=0,height=600, width=800)
  print(dtm_terms)
  dtm_terms
  })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is displaying cross origin content, you could try checking the http header content to see what the `X-frame-options` is set as . If it is set as DENY or SAMEORIGIN you would have to have the same origin for the site content to display in an `iframe`. Otherwise the content will be blocked from rendering.

If the pages have the same origin you could try changing the header options for your web server.

[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67889/why-do-browsers-enforce-the-same-origin-security-policy-on-iframes) link has some good information on it.